# how to get running program in windows xp taskbar in python?

Tags: python, win32gui

I've use this code to get the top level windows. Is there a way to get only running program in the taskbar? Sorry for the format. Thanks

```
def windowEnumerationHandler(hwnd, resultList):
'''Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to generate list of window handle, window text tuples.'''
    resultList.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))
    topWindows = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, topWindows)
```

Comment: Do you mean the notification area?

Comment: No, where all the program is place when minimized

Comment: Check whether the window has an owner or not. If not, it's shown in the taskbar. Also need to check for non top level windows that have WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style.